# Assign an operation when NameError

Tags: python, python-2.x, nameerror

i am trying to get an input to only be a number or an error message is returned and you are asked for the number again.
i want to use input not raw_input and if it returns an error like if you enter "h" i want it to say error and ask the question again.
but if it is either a +ve number or a -ve number continue. i have only managed with using verification on a raw_input and cant get anywhere with using Nameerror exceptions. but it doesnt work for -ve numbers

```
def numbercheck():
    Answercheck =  False
    inputanswer = raw_input("What is your number?")
    while inputanswer.isdigit() == True and any(c.isalpha() for c in inputanswer) == False:
        print "success"
        return
    else:
        if inputanswer.isdigit() == True and any(c.isalpha() for c in inputanswer) == False:
            print "success"
            return
        else:
            print "INVALID NUMBER- Please try again: "
            numbercheck()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking whether each character in the input is a digit and not an alphabetic character (what about special characters?), you should just `try` to parse the number as an `int`, and if that fails, try again.

```
def numbercheck():
    while True:
        try:
            inputanswer = raw_input("What is your number?")
            as_number = int(inputanswer)
            print "success"
            return as_number
        except ValueError:
            print "INVALID NUMBER- Please try again: "
```

Also, `raw_input` is the right way to go. `input` in Python 2 can lead to very bad things. In Python 3, `input` does the same as `raw_input` in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
if inputanswer[0]=="+" or inputanswer[0]=="-":
    inputanswer = inputanswer[1:]
```